# How to make a data member of a class unique for each instance of that class

Tags: c++, class, operator-overloading

This is the code of the program I have written and everything works just perfectly except the part that it has only one requirement. The ID data member of the class Department should be unique for each instance of that class. I have tried using operator overloading to compare the IDs of the Departments created. But the problem with that would be that the comparison should be made in the main driver of the program, and it is required to be made either in the constructor of the class or inside the class.

```
Here is the code

class Department {
public:
    Department(string id) {
        ID = id;
    }
    
    bool operator== (const Department& rhs) {
        return ID == rhs.ID;
    }

    friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& out, const Department& value);
protected:
    string ID;
};

ostream& operator<<(ostream& out, const Department& value)
{
    out << value.ID;
    return out;
}

int main() {
    Department d1("ID-1");
    Department d2("ID-1");
    
    if (d1 == d2) {
        cout << "They are the same";
    }
    else {
        cout << "No the same";
    }
}
```

Comment: It would be easier if the constructor itself would generate ids, then you can ensure that they are generated uniquely. If not, you will need to store a global storage of already reserved IDs *or* storage of pointers to Departments, which you will manage in constructors and destructor of `Department`.

Comment: How would the constructor be able to generate ids by itself i don't understand that.

Comment: Well, let's say that departments get IDs like `"ID-1"`, `"ID-2"`, `"ID-3"`... etc. This can be generated simply by code and you don't even have to verify that there are no duplicates, you simply know that each generated name is different.. However, if departments get more human names, like `"Finance"`, `"HR"`, `"Management"`, then you cannot generate such names and you need a global storage of sorts to verify if there is no other Department that already has such ID.

Comment: Well i just have to make sure that the ID is unique, but then how do i implement it in the code. Because that would mean to create a function that returns a string with a specific format.

Comment: @HermesÇati You could keep a [set](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set) of id strings. Every time you create a new department, check it doesn't exist in the set.

Comment: @jignatius I actually used a vector to store all the IDs ever recorded and ran a binary search to see if it exists and if it does then it asks to override the repeated one. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can make a static attribute that is incremented after each assignment. The static attribute will be the same for all instances.

Comment: I thought of creating a static variable to keep track of the previous one but i can't seem to make it work with strings i can only seem to make it work with integers.

Comment: @HermesÇati `"ID-" + std::to_string(the_static_number)`

Comment: @HermesÇati You can concatenate the string with the Integer value.

Comment: @Sara Sameer I actually tried to keep it as a fixed format and just let the constructor generate a 3 digit int and then concatenate with the string holding the "ID-" part but the problem with that was that every once in a while it would generate the same 3 digit number, but thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

This may be what the previous answer is intending, though this one increments whenever an object is constructed.  That way each object is given essentially a new serial number when it comes to life.

```
class Department {
public:
    Department() {
        ID = "ID_" + std::to_string(IDcount);
        ++IDcount;
    }
    
    bool operator== (const Department& rhs) {
        return ID == rhs.ID;
    }

protected:
    string ID;
    static int IDcount;
};
int Department::IDcount = 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

To ensure that no two instances of a class have the same value for a data-member, you can make its constructor non-public and use a singleton friend class to manage its instances.

```
class Department
{
protected:
    string ID;
    friend class DepartmentCreator;
    Department(string id)
    {
        ID = id;
    }
    Department();
};

class DepartmentCreator
{
private:
    map<string, Department *> dept_instances;
    static DepartmentCreator *this_instance;
    DepartmentCreator();

public:
    DepartmentCreator(const DepartmentCreator &) = delete;
    void operator=(const DepartmentCreator &) = delete;

    static DepartmentCreator *GetCreator();
    Department *GetDepartment(string id);
};

DepartmentCreator *DepartmentCreator::this_instance = nullptr;

DepartmentCreator::DepartmentCreator() {}

DepartmentCreator *DepartmentCreator::GetCreator()
{
    if (!this_instance)
    {
        this_instance = new DepartmentCreator();
    }
    return this_instance;
}

Department *DepartmentCreator::GetDepartment(string id)
{
    if (dept_instances.find(id) == dept_instances.end())
    {
        dept_instances[id] = new Department(id);
    }
    return dept_instances[id];
}
```

Now, you can use it like this:

```
DepartmentCreator *dept_creator = DepartmentCreator::GetCreator();
Department *d1 = dept_creator->GetDepartment("ID-1");
Department *d2 = dept_creator->GetDepartment("ID-1");
```

There is no need to overload `==`. You will always get the same pointer for a given ID.